# How can I pass stdio from a C# console application to Node.js?

Tags: c#, node.js, console-application

I want to link my stdio from a C# console application to Node.js. To better describe my question, I create a sample like below

I have some code like below:

```
IJsEngine engine = new NodeJsEngine(new NodeSettings { UseBuiltinLibrary = true});
engine.ExecuteFile("SpawnServer.js");
```

And my `SpawnServer.js` is like below:

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

console.log('Hi');
process.stdout.write("Hi");
spawn("npx", ["ansible-language-server"].concat(" --stdio"), { stdio: 'inherit' });
```

I like to see `Hi` in my C# console application, *but* I do not know. How can I do it?

Note: All code is in *[visualstudio-ansible](https://github.com/soroshsabz/visualstudio-ansible/tree/features/4-support-ansible-language-server)* (GitHub)

I added this question in the [GitHub Javascript.NodeJS](https://github.com/JeringTech/Javascript.NodeJS/issues/163#issue-1634778220) project.

Comment: Re *"I add this question"*: In other words, [crossposted](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crosspost#Verb) it to [GitHub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub)

Comment: What is "stdio"? [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)) and [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29)? A (literal) command line parameter? Something else? What is it for? Can you elaborate?

Comment: You want to pass control of the Console class to an external application? Sounds like you are looking for something more along the lines of a named pipe or other communication method from you client to your server and vice versa.